# jQuery Dropdown by a jQuery Dummy

Tags: jquery, html

```
function rightFrame(e) {
    $('#' + e).css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '30px',
        'visibility': 'visible'
    });
    $('#' + e).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').mouseover(function(e) {
        rightFrame($(this).data('item'));
    });
    $('.link').mouseout(function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
            if ($(this).is(':hover') == true) {
                $('.right').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Okay just to qualify here, I know practically nothing about jQuery or JavaScript. I started with the base code to get the dropdown-type box to appear, and then fiddled with it to make it as it is. My goal is to have the dropdown appear when you hover over the link while still allowing you to click inside the dropdown, as a dropdown navigation should. But, as I said, I'm kind of a dummy when it comes to jQuery/JS. Help!

PS - Link refers to the link that you hover over in order for the dropdown to appear. Right refers to the dropdown itself.

```
<div id="leftcontent">
    <hr size="1" color="#555" />
        <a href="#"><div class="link" data-item="r1">HOME<br /><span class="littlelink">THE HOMEPAGE</span></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="right" id="r1">asdf</div></a>
    <hr size="1" color="#555" />
        <a href="#"><div class="link" data-item="r2">PORTFOLIO<br /><span class="littlelink">SOME OF MY WORK</span></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="right" id="r2">asdf</div></a>
    <hr size="1" color="#555" />
        <a href="#"><div class="link" data-item="r3">PRICES<br /><span class="littlelink">YOUR INVESTMENT</span></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="right" id="r3">asdf</div></a>
    <hr size="1" color="#555" />
        <a href="#"><div class="link" data-item="r4">CONTACT<br /><span class="littlelink">GET IN TOUCH</span></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="right" id="r4">asdf</div></a>
    <hr size="1" color="#555" />
</div><!-- end leftcontent -->
```

Comment: please share the html also

Comment: can you add your html code in question....

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to do that.

Comment: so the `right` element is the dropdown which should slidedown on hover of the `link` element

Comment: Correct. Right now, it appears properly, but it only disappears if you hover over another main link and then its dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your drop down items as children for your button this way they don't disappear when your mouse goes to items ( only if items are placed right next to the button )

so for your problem I'd suggest

```
<div class="link"> 
    <a href="..."> ... </a>
    <div class="right">
         <a href="..."> ... </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes mouseout not triggering properly so just use `slideToggle();` `fadeToggle();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').mouseover(function(e) {
    //$(this).closest('a').next('a').find('.right').fadeToggle(400); //ITS FOR YOUR OLD HTML
             $(this).find('.right').slideToggle(400);
            //above 50 is speed of animation
    });

});
```

use this html for dropdown

```
<ul>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="#">Link....</a>
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#">Sublink-1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. I want the dropdown to remain indefinitely until it is no longer being hovered over. Would this not make it disappear after a certain amount of time regardless?